# phpinfo() showing display_errors as off despite php.ini setting it as on and command line php -i showing it is on

Tags: php

I am using php 7 and nginx together.

Baffling problem - phpinfo() shows display_errors as off. Going to command line and running:

> php -i | grep 'display_errors'

returns

> display_errors => STDOUT => STDOUT

My understanding is that means display errors should be on. This command confirms I am using the correct ini file:

> php -i | grep php.ini

As it returns this output:

> Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php/7.0/cli

That is the file I am using.

I have restarted nginx with

> systemctl restart nginx

I have run out of options. The best I can do is is set it locally at the top of my files with:

> ini_set('display_errors', 1)

Running phpinfo() afterwards shows display_errors is on "locally" but off for "master" i.e. on for a per script basis. This is ok but won't detect syntax errors, so I want it on for both columns in phpinfo without having to set it in each script via ini_set.

Please note - I am aware this question has been asked before however I have yet to encounter someone who still has this problem after modifying the correct php.ini file and confirming via php -i that the display_errors value is correct.

Edit: Forgot to mention, I have also modified the php.ini file in php/7.0/fpm and restarted nginx with no success

Comment: The command line `php` and a web server's PHP typically have separate configuration files…

Comment: @deceze I was wondering the same. Isn't `/etc/php/7.0/cli` for console only?

Comment: Yeah, that's why it says `cli` in there.

Comment: @deceze I have also modified the php.ini file in php/7.0/fpm and restarted nginx with no success

Comment: You probably also need to restart PHP FPM.

Comment: @deceze You are correct. I used this command service php7.0-fpm restart and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about nginx, but I have 2 php.inis in my default installation with apache.

One for cli ( /etc/php5/cli ) and one for apache ( /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini ).

Your commandline calls definetly use the one for cli, i guess your webserver uses "the other one" for nginx.

I wanted them to be equal and created a softlink...

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I have also modified the php.ini file in php/7.0/fpm and restarted nginx with no success